# Split value of a html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, split

I would like to split some content from an "a" html tag. I was starting over with jquery. My code is like this but it is not working:

```
$("a.uribb").each(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("http://dereferer.org/?", "");
    $(this).append(+id+);
});
```

​
And the HTML tag is this:

```
<a href="http://dereferer.org/?http://example.com/" target="_blank" class="uribb">
    http://example.com/
</a>
```

I wanted to split out the `http://dereferer.org/?` part and leave the other there. How could I do this?

Comment: What is the intended result? `href="http://example.com/"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `.text()` instead of `.append()` if you want to replace the content. Also, there is no need for the `+` before and after the id.

You could try this instead:

```
var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("http://dereferer.org/?", "");
$(this).text(id);
```

**Update**

Reading through the question again, I'm not sure if you want to replace the content of the `a`-tag or the the value of the href. In case of the latter, try this:

```
var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("http://dereferer.org/?", "");
$(this).attr("href", id);
```

**Notice**

Since jQuery 1.6, it is preferred to use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `.attr()`.

Comment: Wouldn't you try for `$(this).text(id);` instead?

Comment: These is not solving the problem the link still appears with the dereferer.org text at the beginning
Update:
I want to replace the href value of the a tag.

Comment: @drderp Valid point, in this case `.text()` is probably more appropriate. Updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: @user1430562 Have you tried my updated answer using `.attr()` instead?

Comment: your `.prop()` link has an extra `;` at the end, which is kinda making the page 404

Answer (score 1):

How about that?

```
$("a.uribb").attr("href", function(i, val) {
    return val.substring(val.indexOf("?") + 1);
});​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zQdL4/

---

It's interesting but for your markup the following code should also work :)

```
$("a.uribb").attr("href", function() {
    return $.trim(this.innerHTML);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Right, so what you want is this.

```
<a href="http://example.com/">...
```

Try this.

```
$("a.uribb").each(function() {
    var indirect_url = $(this).prop("href");
    var direct_url = indirect_url.replace("http://dereferer.org/?", "")
    $(this).prop('href', direct_url);
});
```

You could of course do this in fewer lines, but this way it's clear what's going on. Specifically, `replace()` does *not* modify the string it operates on.